# Multivariate Normal PDF for use in Ceres using Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, ceres-solver

I am trying to write a templated method that computes the probability density of a given input for a multivariate normal distribution. It takes both the input, the mean vector and covariance matrix as input.

I want to use this method within a Ceres cost functor, where the input variable and the mean/covariance is fixed. Currently, the method looks as follows:

```
template <int Dim, class Scalar>
Scalar mvn_norm_pdf(const Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, Dim, 1>   & input,
                    const Eigen::Matrix<float,  Dim, 1>   & mean,
                    const Eigen::Matrix<float,  Dim, Dim> & covariance)
{
    static const Scalar log_sqrt_2_pi = Scalar(0.5 * std::log(2 * M_PI));

    typedef Eigen::LLT<Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, Dim, Dim>> Cholesky;
    Cholesky chol(covariance.template cast<Scalar>());
    if (chol.info() != Eigen::Success) throw "Decomposition failed!";
    const typename Cholesky::Traits::MatrixL & L = chol.matrixL();

    Scalar quad_form = (L.solve(input - mean.template cast<Scalar>())).squaredNorm();
    Scalar det = L.determinant();

    return ceres::exp(Scalar(-input.rows()) * log_sqrt_2_pi - 0.5 * quad_form) / det;
}
```

This throws a compilation error within Eigen, though, specifically on the line where `det` is set to `L.determinant()`. The message:

```
Eigen/src/Core/TriangularMatrix.h:371:16: error: could not convert ‘1’ from ‘int’ to ‘Eigen::TriangularView<const Eigen::Matrix<ceres::Jet<double, 7>, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3>, 1u>::Scalar {aka ceres::Jet<double, 7>}’
         return 1;
                ^
Eigen/src/Core/TriangularMatrix.h:373:16: error: could not convert ‘0’ from ‘int’ to ‘Eigen::TriangularView<const Eigen::Matrix<ceres::Jet<double, 7>, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3>, 1u>::Scalar {aka ceres::Jet<double, 7>}’
         return 0;
```

Looking in the mentioned Eigen source file, I find:

```
Scalar determinant() const
{
  if (Mode & UnitDiag)
    return 1;
  else if (Mode & ZeroDiag)
    return 0;
  else
    return m_matrix.diagonal().prod();
}
```

So, as far as I understand, the problem comes from the fact that Eigen could return 1 or 0 (which are `int`s), and an int cannot be converted to a `ceres::Jet`. Am I right here, and if so, what would be the right way to deal with this?

Comment: It should be possible to just write `const Scalar det = L.diagonal().prod()`.